# Access/Refresh Token Usage

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm in the same scenario with this question 
[Refresh Token usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852054/refresh-token-usage)
when Two or more device need to be logged in at the same time with same credentials.

If i use a different scope to identify the device, then i can't set the scope as  openid and i can't have a JWT token nor /userinfo endpoint.

Is there a solution to have 2 differents access token for the same clientId/clientKey/login/password by provided another parameter than the scope ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scope you can have multiple values. So you can try

```
-d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=device_1 openid"
```